# How do I make an index of a double digit number as one, and not two separate index numbers?

Tags: javascript, encryption

I am trying to code the Hill cipher, which assigns each letter of the alphabet with a number, starting from 0. So A = 0 and Z = 25. With what I have so far, it correctly makes this numeric alphabet but when I insert K as the message to encrypt to its assigned number, the output is 1, and not 10. So if I type in KLM, the output is 101. I pretty sure I need to fix the second for loop.

```js
var plainAlphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

var cipherAlphabet = '';

    for(var i = 0; i < plainAlphabet.length; i++){
        var letter = plainAlphabet.charAt(i);//getting the character
        var index = plainAlphabet.indexOf(letter);
        letter = index;
        cipherAlphabet += letter;


    }


    var encryptedMsg = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < msg.length; i++){
        var letter = msg.charAt(i); 
        var index = plainAlphabet.indexOf(letter);
        encryptedMsg += cipherAlphabet.charAt(index);
    }
```

Comment: You need to pad single digits with a leading zero. Then always look at 2 digits at a time. Else how would you decode 23?

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from the fact that `cipherAlphabet.charAt(index)` will return THE only char at the index indicated. So if will give you `1` because it is the first char of `10`.

Here is a functional code:

```js
msg = ""
    var encryptedMsg = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < msg.length; i++){
        var letter = msg.charAt(i); // (1)
        let cipher = letter.charCodeAt(0)-65 // (2)
        encryptedMsg += cipher; 
    }
```

Explanation  :

(1) You get the char at the given index

(2) You are getting the ASCII code of the letter and you subtract it from the A ASCII code (65).

I think that this is the shortest way to make it work.

If you want to continue on what you have done, you can transform `var cipherAlphabet = ''` into an array `var cipherAlphabet = []` and then, access the element of the array. So you would replace your last ligne `encryptedMsg += cipherAlphabet[i]`.

Note that to add an element to an array, you have to use `cipherAlphabet.push(element)`

Comment: thanks! just to clarify, you put 0 in letter.charCodeAt() since the variable letter will only have one index which is the letter chosen. sorry if this explanation is confusing.

Comment: Yes, you got it ;) If it solved your issue, you can mark it as solved :)